# Angular directive to wrap a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate the cubeportfolio jquery plugin into an angular app. But I'm stuck right now.

My directive:

```
var app = angular.module('App');
    app.directive('iso', function($timeout){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            scope: { data: '=',},
            templateUrl: 's.html',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
               var options = {Options there};
               var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('#grid-container'));
               scope.$watch('data', function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        e.cubeportfolio(options);
                    });
                },true);

            }

        };
    });
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, Service){
    Service
        .find()
        .$promise
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.services = res;
        })
});
```

index.html:

```
<div id="grid-container" class="cbp" iso data="services"></div>
```

s.html

```
<div class="cbp-item {{ s.cataloge }}" ng-repeat="s in data"></div>
```

Result:

> e.cubeportfolio is not a function

I'd like to understand the best way to handle them. Thanks!

Comment: If you include jquery before angular, angular.element should return a true jquery instance, with all its methods (including 3rd party ones). However, it seems that's not the case for you. Are you including jquery and cubeportfolio's .js files before the angular include?

Comment: thanks you, I have included jquery and cubeportfolio's .js files before the angular include. But result: Error: cubeportfolio is already initialized. Destroy it before initialize again!

Answer (score 0):

make sure cubeportfolio is loaded already
and withing your link function

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
 element.cubeportfolio(scope.$eval(attrs.data));
})
```